# Upload image uisng Pre signed AWS URL in android

Tags: java, android

I am working on a app which upload signature image ([signaturepad](https://github.com/gcacace/android-signaturepad)) library to s3 uisng pre signed url. Initially I need to request another server for presigned url with body look like

```
{
    "groupId": "56adfe62-949c-42e9-8b54-dc034559affa",
    "formId": "56adfe62-949c-42e9-8b54-dc034559affa",
    "fileExtension": "bmp",
    "fileName": "factory.bmp",
    "contentType": "image/bmp",
    "fileSize": 2388
}
```

This provides a resposne like

```
{
    "status": 0,
    "message": "Success",
    "response": {
        "getUrl": "https://static.java.senpiper.com/56adfe62-949c-42e9-8b54-dc034559affa/059df0e4-7cf4-458c-9e9f-0048a471ce6e.bmp",
        "putUrl": "https://senpiper-staging.s3.amazonaws.com/public/56adfe62-949c-42e9-8b54-dc034559affa/059df0e4-7cf4-458c-9e9f-0048a471ce6e.png?x-amz-acl=public-read&AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAJXV3MWPXTUWD2IKA&Expires=1573646319&Signature=8kN5LcdtH2YzsSwqojcpIj2T8mA%3D"
    }
}
```

Then now I have to use put url to upload my signature pad image(.bmp file) from my andriod to s3 but I am unable to upload it through android app it throws error mesasge "Signature Doesn't match" but with postman software uploding of image is success. So can anyone help me to implement this in android app?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because OP wants people to do it for him/her.

Comment: Sorry if you think like that, I haven't mentioned that i need complete code or project. I just ask to help me to implement it and I mentioned that i implemented it but there is an error from server side i.e signature doesn't match.

Comment: read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Steps to get image upload into aws servers
[signturepad](https://github.com/gcacace/android-signaturepad)

1. Request external servers for presigned url.
2. Read get_url from the json response from the servers.
3. Use get_url for uploading image or any file to aws servers.

**Read Canvas to bitmap and save to storage**

```
Bitmap signature =signaturePad.getSignatureBitmap();
File sign_path=SaveImage(signature);
RequestBody requestBody=RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("image/jpg"),sign_path);
```

```
private File SaveImage(Bitmap signature) {
        ContextWrapper root=new ContextWrapper(getApplicationContext());
        File Dir=root.getDir("profile",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        if(!Dir.exists()){
            Dir.mkdir();
        }
        String S_Name="Image_signature.jpg";
        File file=new File(Dir,S_Name);
        try {
            FileOutputStream outputStream= new FileOutputStream(file);
            signature.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG,100,outputStream);
            outputStream.flush();
            outputStream.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return file;
    }
```

**Requesting external servers for pre signed email**

```
Retrofit retro_pre_upload=new Retrofit.Builder()
         .baseUrl("https://stagingtest.staging.senpiper.com/api/core/")
         .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
         .build();
pre_upload image_pre=retro_pre_upload.create(pre_upload.class);
```

**Now Build Json body for api request**

```
   JsonObject jsonObject=new JsonObject();
   jsonObject.addProperty("groupId", groupid);
   jsonObject.addProperty("formId", formid);
   jsonObject.addProperty("fileExtension", "jpg");
   jsonObject.addProperty("fileName", sign_path.getName());
   jsonObject.addProperty("contentType", "image/jpg");
   jsonObject.addProperty("fileSize",sign_path.length());
```

**pre_upload.java** Interface

```
public interface pre_upload {
    @Headers({"Contet-Type: application/json"})
    @POST("media/group")
    Call<Object> upload(@Header("auth") String auth,
                        @Body JsonObject json);
}
```

**Image_upload.java** Interface for image upload to AWS servers.

```
public interface Image_upload{
    @Headers({"Content-Type: image/jpg"})
    @PUT()
    Call<Void> aws_upload(@Url(value = "url", encoded = true) String path,
                          @Body RequestBody image);
}
```

Call APIs with auth-token and jsonbody

```
Call<Object> pre_call=image_pre.upload(token,jsonObject);
pre_call.enqueue(new Callback<Object>(){
@Override
public void onResponse(Call<Object> call, Response<Object> pre_upload_response) {
       if(pre_upload_response.code() == 200) {
          // get url from json response 
          LinkedTreeMap pre_upload_url_res = (LinkedTreeMap) pre_upload_response.body();
          String image_get_url = ((LinkedTreeMap) 
           pre_upload_url_res.get("response")).get("getUrl").toString();
          //Call another API with presigned url and request body
          Retrofit retro_image_upload = new Retrofit.Builder()
                                 .baseUrl("https://www.Dummy-URL.com")
                                 .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                                 .build();
         Image_upload final_upload = retro_image_upload.create(Image_upload.class);
         Call<Void> image_upload_call = final_upload.aws_upload(image_get_url,requestBody);
         image_upload_call.enqueue(new Callback<Void>() {
           @Override
          public void onResponse(Call<Void> call, Response<Void> image_response) {
             if (image_response.code() == 200) {
                  //Do something
                }
            }
         public void onFailure(Call<Object> call, Throwable t) {
             Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Something went wrong", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();}
});         

}
else{
//do something may be toast notification.
}
}
@Override
public void onFailure(Call<Void> call, Throwable t) {                                        
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Something went Worng", 
        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
});
```

Comment: For `image_upload_call`, you are passing image_get_url. So getUrl is used to PUT an image instead of putUrl?